# How to parse more than one sentence from text file using Stanford dependency parse?

Tags: parsing, python-3.x, nltk, stanford-nlp, triples

I have a text file which have many line, i wanted to parse all sentences, but it seems like i get all sentences but parse only the first sentence, not sure where m i making mistake.

```
import nltk
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser
dependency_parser = StanfordDependencyParser(  model_path="edu\stanford\lp\models\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz")
txtfile =open('sample.txt',encoding="latin-1")
s=txtfile.read()
print(s)
result = dependency_parser.raw_parse(s)
for i in result:
print(list(i.triples()))
```

but it give only the first sentence parse tripples not other sentences, any help ?

```
'i like this computer'
'The great Buddha, the .....'
'My Ashford experience .... great experience.'


[[(('i', 'VBZ'), 'nsubj', ("'", 'POS')), (('i', 'VBZ'), 'nmod', ('computer', 'NN')), (('computer', 'NN'), 'case', ('like', 'IN')), (('computer', 'NN'), 'det', ('this', 'DT')), (('computer', 'NN'), 'case', ("'", 'POS'))]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split the text first. You're currently parsing the literal text you posted with quotes and everything. This is evident by this part of the parsing result: `("'", 'POS')`

To do that you seem to be able to use `ast.literal_eval` on each line. Note that an apostrophe (in a word like "don't") will ruin the formatting and you'll have to handle the apostrophes yourself with something like `line = line[1:-1]`:

```
import ast
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser
dependency_parser = StanfordDependencyParser(  model_path="edu\stanford\lp\models\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz")

with open('sample.txt',encoding="latin-1") as f:
    lines = [ast.litral_eval(line) for line in f.readlines()]

for line in lines:
    parsed_lines = dependency_parser.raw_parse(line)

# now parsed_lines should contain the parsed lines from the file
```

Comment: ok got it, but what if i dont have quotes text, only simple text like i like car etc, still i need ast.literal_eval. i think it doesnt work with simple text... so how to handle that ?

Comment: If it's simple text you don't need to do parsing. Just read the lines as they are.

Comment: i am parsing these lines for other purpose, i want to get nouns and adjective from parse triples. so now how to parse simple text so that i get all Nouns and adjective from parse text, any modification ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I answered the given question. You were only using a `read` which read the entire file and you didn't parse it. If you have any followup questions feel free to post them in a different post after making an effort solving them yourself and presenting the effort in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser
dependency_parser = StanfordDependencyParser(model_path="edu\stanford\lp\models\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz")

with open('sample.txt') as fin:
    sents = fin.readlines()
result = dep_parser.raw_parse_sents(sents)
for parse in results:
    print list(parse.triples())
```

Do check the [docstring code](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.parse.html#nltk.parse.stanford.StanfordDependencyParser) or [demo code in repository](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/stanford.py#L292) for examples, they're usually very helpful.